# Solve the Second Order Nonhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm stuck on this problem since I can't find any material in my textbook or internet to solve this. Any help?

$$2x^2 \cdot y'' - x \cdot y' + y = x$$

$$y'' - \frac{y'}{2x} + \frac{y}{2x^2} = \frac{1}{2x}$$

Comment: **Hints:** for the first one, use Euler-Cauchy. Is the second one $\dfrac{1}{2} x$ or $\dfrac{1}{2 x}$? Using MathJax will eliminate readability issues.

Comment: @Moo The second one is 1/(2x)

Comment: Same hints for the second one, multiply by $x^2$, use Euler-Cauchy and Variation of Parameters or use $y = v x$.

Comment: Since you want somehow to get rid of powers of $x$ coinciding with the degree of the derivative of $y$, I would try something like $y(x) = x^k \cdot ln(x)$ and figure out which $k$ looks "nice".

Answer (score 2):

The equation is 
$$ 2x^2y'' - xy' + y = x $$

This is an inhomogeneous [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) of second order. Make the substitution $x = e^t$ and $y(x) = u(t)$ to get
$$ 2u'' - 3u' + u = e^t $$

Which you can solve using the [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients#Examples) to obtain the general solution
$$ u(t) = te^t + c_1e^t + c_2e^{t/2} $$
$$ \implies y(x) = x\ln x + c_1 x + c_2 \sqrt{x} $$

---

An alternative approach is try to find solutions of the form $y = x^m$. Plugging this into the original equation, we obtain the characteristic polynomial
$$ 2m(m-1) - m + 1 = 0 $$

which has roots $m=1$, $m=1/2$. Therefore the homogeneous solution is
$$ y_h(x) = c_1x + c_2\sqrt{x} $$

Knowing this, we can use [variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) to find a particular solution of the form
$$ y_p(x) = x\ v_1(x) + \sqrt{x}\ v_2(x) $$

where the coefficient functions satisfy

$$ \left\{ \begin{aligned} x{v_1}' + \sqrt{x}{v_2}' &= 0 \\
{v_1}' + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}{v_2}' &= \frac{1}{2x} \end{aligned} \right. $$

Solving the above system gives
$$ {v_1}' = \frac{1}{x}, \quad {v_2}' = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} $$

Integrating and recombining gives $y_p = x\ln x - 2x$, of which the second term is absorbed into $y_h$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

$$y'' - \frac{y'}{2x} + \frac{y}{2x^2} = \frac{1}{2x}$$

$$y'' -\frac 1 2 ( \frac{y'x}{x^2} - \frac{y}{x^2})= \frac{1}{2x}$$

$$y'' -\frac 1 2 ( \frac{y'x-y}{x^2})= \frac{1}{2x}$$

$$y'' -\frac 1 2 ( \frac{y}{x})'= \frac{1}{2x}$$

Integrate:

$$y' -\frac{y}{2x}=\int \frac{dx}{2x}$$

$$y' -\frac{y}{2x}=\frac{\ln(x)}{2}+K$$

Which is easy to solve ....

Comment: Both lines are the same equation.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't pay attention while i was integrating the equation...